# Resize of section header in UITableViewController not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to resize a section header, according to a selection in the headers `UISegmentedControl`.
For some reason, it just doesn't want to work. I have tried with `[self.tableView beginUpdates];` and `[self.tableView endUpdates];` before, around and after the change-height code.. but it just act weird.

I get it to hide and show content, but it seems to allocate a different height for the view even thought the size of the header should be less.

This is what happens:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3077127/Problem3.mov

This is my code:

```
typedef enum {
    kSearchTypeFrom = 0,
    kSearchTypeTo
} kSearchType;

@interface MainVC ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) FilterVC *filterView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) kSearchType searchType;

@end

@implementation MainVC

@synthesize filterView = _filterView;
@synthesize searchType = _searchType;

[...]

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.searchType = kSearchTypeFrom;

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:@"Test"];

    return cell;
}

- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (!self.filterView) {
        self.filterView = [[FilterVC alloc] init];
        [self.filterView.view setBackgroundColor:self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor];
    }

    [self.filterView.segment setSelectedSegmentIndex:self.searchType];

    [self.filterView.segment addTarget:self action:@selector(didChangeSegmentSelection:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    return self.filterView.view;
}

- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.searchType == kSearchTypeFrom)
    {
        return 130;
    }
    else {
        return 100;
    }
}

#pragma mark - Height change table section

- (void)didChangeSegmentSelection:(UISegmentedControl*)segment
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    self.searchType = segment.selectedSegmentIndex;

    NSLog(@"Selected: %d", segment.selectedSegmentIndex);

    if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        [self.filterView.changeToText setHidden:NO];
        [self.filterView.changeToButton setHidden:NO];

        [self.filterView.fromButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }
    else {
        [self.filterView.changeToText setHidden:YES];
        [self.filterView.changeToButton setHidden:YES];

        [self.filterView.fromButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    [self.filterView.view needsUpdateConstraints];
}

[...]
```

The `FilterVC` class is nothing more than an UIViewController containing the following:

```
#import "InsetTextField.h"

@interface FilterVC : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet InsetTextField *amountField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segment;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *fromButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *changeToText;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *changeToButton;

@end
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your dropbox link doesn't seem to be valid.

Comment: Sorry... holiday project.. and bad wifi connection at resort. Didn't got uploaded. I am trying now again.

Comment: @TimothyMoose The file is uploaded and should work. Thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate to trying to animate, you could try reloading the table using the following:

```
- (void)didChangeSegmentSelection:(UISegmentedControl*)segment
{
    //[self.tableView beginUpdates];

    self.searchType = segment.selectedSegmentIndex;

    NSLog(@"Selected: %d", segment.selectedSegmentIndex);

    if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        [self.filterView.changeToText setHidden:NO];
        [self.filterView.changeToButton setHidden:NO];

        [self.filterView.fromButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }
    else {
        [self.filterView.changeToText setHidden:YES];
        [self.filterView.changeToButton setHidden:YES];

        [self.filterView.fromButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }

    //[self.tableView endUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.filterView.view needsUpdateConstraints];
}
```

EDIT:

How about a variable to track height? This is sloppy code, but if the concept works, you can refactor it:

```
// Declare a variable
@proprty (strong, nonatomic) float headerHeight;

// Use that variable for defining the height
- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.searchType == kSearchTypeFrom)
    {
        headerHeight = 130;
    }
    else {
        headerHeight = 100;
    }

    return headerHeight
}
```

Then change that variable:

```
- (void)didChangeSegmentSelection:(UISegmentedControl*)segment
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    self.searchType = segment.selectedSegmentIndex;

    // Change the variable used for the header height
    if (self.searchType == kSearchTypeFrom)
    {
        headerHeight = 130;
    }
    else {
        headerHeight = 100;
    }

    NSLog(@"Selected: %d", segment.selectedSegmentIndex);

    if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        [self.filterView.changeToText setHidden:NO];
        [self.filterView.changeToButton setHidden:NO];

        [self.filterView.fromButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }
    else {
        [self.filterView.changeToText setHidden:YES];
        [self.filterView.changeToButton setHidden:YES];

        [self.filterView.fromButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    [self.filterView.view needsUpdateConstraints];
}
```

Comment: That does work, however... I like the animation, which is part of what I am trying to accomplish.